# Are there any standard options available for Distributed Jmeter Deployment

Tags: jmeter

Sample Use Case :

I want to use Distributed Command line Jmeter, with 10 slaves or more

- Do I have to manually copy Jmeter TAR/ZIP on all these slave machines and perform necessary setup ??
- Are there any tools or shell scripts available to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with non-GUI mode? One thing that it lets you do (besides easy automation) is run distributed tests with the -R command.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

You get less information as the test is running (ie, no runtime graphs), but if you configure it correctly, you can ramp up tests, repeat tests, etc, very easily.